# VBA code to delete a record from a table through a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

1. I want to delete a record from a table called projects through a subform called projects_subform which is on the Search Form.

   I have this code
2. I also want to update a record by clicking on a record in the subform to open the Project form for editing and update but my code is not working. It only opens the project form without the record to edit

This is the code I have

```
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
```

Second code for editing and updating

```
Private Sub Edit_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "formname", acNormal, , "[autonumberfield]=" & Me.[autonumberfield]
DoCmd.OpenForm fmrproject, acNormal, [ProjectID], , [ProjectID] = " & Me.[fmrProject, acFormEdit]"

End Sub
```

I expect a record to be deleted in both table and subform because the subform is directly linked to the table.

Comment: Your first code snippet is not an actual subroutine (out of order and empty). Your second sub is doing exactly what you describe... it is opening forms. If you want to delete the record you are going to have to perform an SQL or recordset operation inside of that sub.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt: This is the code behind the delete button but it doesn’t work.
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
    Msg = "You are about to delete this record."
  Style = vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2
  Title = "Continue?"
  Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
  If Response = vbOK Then 
  Else
    MsgBox "No record deleted", vbOKOnly, "No changes made"
  End If
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * FROM [" & Projects & "] WHERE ProjectID=" & Me.Projects_subform.Form.ProjectID & ";”
    Me.Projects_subform.Form.Requery
        End If
            End If
End Sub

Comment: Could you edit your question to put the code into the stub that Erik A created? It's hard to read, but that looks like Macro formatting copied and pasted into the VBA console, which should be throwing all kinds of errors. Have you stepped through it?